# Different type of prob posed; moderator attention needed

Tags: performance, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am just trying to figure out why

```
3^2500 < log(n) < 5log(n) < nlog(n^2) < nlog(n) < n^270
```

this is not true. This is from fastest to slowest.

Could anyone tell me why this is wrong?

I am confused with the middle part 5log(n) < nlog(n^2) < nlog(n)

Don't they share the same order of magnitude?

One more question,

```
sum = 0
 for i in myIntegerList:
   if i > 0:
     sum += i
```

For this code fragment, the best case and the worst case would be O (n) right?

I am thinking that way because for loop will have a magnitude of n regardless

how many element myIntegerList contains? Also, there is no operation or

statement that results in the ending of the code.

Comment: Why would you think that  nlog(n^2) < nlog(n)  ?

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- 3^2500 is O(1)
- log(n) is O(log n)
- 5log(n) is O(log n) as well, but a higher constant
- nlog(n²) is O(n·log n²) = O(2·n·log n) = O(n·log n)
- nlog(n) is O(n·log n) as well, but a smaller constant
- n^270 is O(n²⁷⁰)

So correct order is:

O(3^2500) < O(log(n)) < O(5·log(n)) < O(n·log(n)) < O(n·log(n^2)) < O(n^270)

Note it isn't correct to use comparisons in these cases without big O notation.

The summation is O(n), *n* being the length of the list, in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused with the middle part 5log(n) < nlog(n^2) < nlog(n)
>
> Don't they share the same order of magnitude?

Considering n is very large :

`log(n^2)` > `log(n)`.

`5log(n) ~ log(n)`

`nlog(n) > 5log(n)`  because 5 is a constant co-efficient.

thus the right answer is:

`13^2500 < log(n) < 5log(n) < nlog(n) < nlog(n^2) < n^27`

> For this code fragment, the best case and the worst case would be O
>   (n) right?

Yes. You iterating over all the elements in `myIntegerList`. Where `n` is the number of elements in `myIntegerList`.

> I am thinking that way because for loop will have a magnitude of n
>   regardless
>
> how many element myIntegerList contains?

Wrong. It depends on the number of elements `myIntegerList` contains. Also, the `for` loop iterates over all elements in `myIntegerList` and stops after it is done iterating. The program will automatically end after the completion of the `for` loop.